# SQL - How to create second query based on first

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have two tabes: *Part_Stock* and *Part_Vendor*.

The first task is to query to *Part_Stock* to return items that are stored at a specific stock location (*CON1C7C*). Once the items at that location are returned, I need to locate the *company part number* which is also in that table, and query to *Part_Vendor*, so that I can return the items with the *company part number* from the *Part_Stock* table and match it to the *Manufacturer Part Number*, which are both located in the *Part_Vendor* table.

Currently I have it so that I query to *Part_Stock* to get the company part numbers, and then I query to *Part_Vendor* by manually inputting the *company part numbers*.

Now there is only 6 parts right now so it's not too bad, but eventually the list will grow exponentially.

**Is there any way to get the same results without having to write out every part number?**

I currently have:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please, use formatted text instead of pictures. Also tag the dbms you're using.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I assume that second table is in different database (because of `use EXACTMAXIMET` statement) 
You can create a table variable, fill it with PartNumber values and then use this table to make a condition for another select.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (PartNumber VARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO @t (PartNumber)
SELECT PartNumber
FROM [Part_Stock]...

USE EXACTMAXIMET

SELECT *
FROM [Part_Vendor]
WHERE PRTNUM_07 IN (
        SELECT PartNumber
        FROM @t
        )
```

Comment: This can be simplified to one select, as per @Siyual's answer below

Comment: Yes, in general, that is better approach. But in some situations I use this one. Usually when I want to prevent locking caused by joining tables from different databases (e.g. busy production DB and idle Logs DB)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a `JOIN`:

```
Select  V.*
From    Part_Stock                      S
Join    Exactmaximet.dbo.Part_Vendor    V   On  V.Prtnum_07 = S.Prtnum_07
Where   S.Stk_06 Like '%CON1C7C%'
```

*Note: I'm making an assumption that the `Part_Stock` column you're getting the `Prtnum_07` value from is also named `Prtnum_07`.*